# Ambiguous type name

Tags: c#, types

I have an issue with the shadowed visibility of types. Let's assume the following code:

```
namespace A {
    class B {
        int V1;
        class A {
            class B { }
            void Foo() {
                A.B b; 
                // "b" should be of the first type "B", 
                // but it actually points to A.B.A.B
                b.V1 = 1; //Compile error
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I declare a variable of Type "A.B" (where "A" should be the namespace, not the nested class "A") at the place, where "b" is declared?

Comment: you of course realize that even if you could do it, this code is not maintainable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the "global"-keyword:

`global::A.B b;`

Answer (score 4):

You can use an alias:

```
using ClassB = A.B;
```

Now `ClassB` refers to the type you want.

However, I would very strongly urge you to reconsider your class names so this is no longer a problem.